# How to build VBA Loop with if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA codes and still in learning process.
I am working on the project where I have to populate userform data to each worksheet ("TMA01 to TMA31" Sheet Name) based on Combo Box value (for example if the combo box value "01" then the userform data should transfer to TMA01 sheet and so on).

Kindly help and thank you in advance

I have tried the below code but not successful

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Me.Combday.Value = "01" Then
        ws("TMA01").Active     'Sheetname(TMA01) 
    End If

    ws.Range("B2").Value = Me.TextEmpnameUF3.Text
    ws.Range("B3").Value = Me.TextDep.Text
    ws.Range("B4").Value = Me.Combday.Text
    ws.Range("C4").Value = Me.Combmonth.Text
    ws.Range("D4").Value = Me.Combyear.Text
next
```

Comment: [Introducing the for-if anti-pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793). `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TMA" & Me.Combday.Value)`.

Comment: In general there is no need to `.Activate` or `.Select` anything so long as you have a variable that references the object. In your case `ws` should reference the worksheet you want to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you may set ws with combobox directly.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

' validate ComboBox
If Combday.Value <> "" Then
    'set ws with value ComboBox
    Set ws = Sheets("TM" & Combday.Value)
    ws.Range("B2").Value = Me.TextEmpnameUF3.Text
    ws.Range("B3").Value = Me.TextDep.Text
    ws.Range("B4").Value = Me.Combday.Text
    ws.Range("C4").Value = Me.Combmonth.Text
    ws.Range("D4").Value = Me.Combyear.Text
End If
```